# How do I move items in an array to the immediate next index?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array of objects which I need to iterate,modify and shift, I'm looking for an optimal solution for this.Please can you help me?

Assume that I have an array with 50 objects with the last two indexes containing invalid objects, what I'm aiming at doing is to remove them by duplicating two of the valid entries at a specified index.

```
var entries = profile.FindAll(entry=>entry.Date == DateTime.Now);

for(int i=0;i<entries.Count;i++)
{
if(i==2)
//store the object at the 2nd position to the 4th index
//However before storing this in the 4th index store the object in the 4th index to 5th index and the 5th index in the 6th..and so on

if(i==3)
//store the object at the 3rd position to the 5th index
//However before storing this in the 5th index store the object in the 5th index to the 6th index and so on..

}

//Basiacally once 'am out of this loop the items in the 2nd and 3rd index should be stored in the 4th and 5th index respectively, and the items in the 4th and 5th should be stored in the consecutive next index
//Another complication to the story is that items in 2nd and 3rd indexes should be copied to 4th & 5th indexes at the same time, so that they are moved.Same should be the case of the consecutive indexes as well.
//This way once I reach the end of the loop the items in the last two indexes of the array should be chucked out with duplicated values of 2nd and 3rd in 4th and 5th respectively and the array shifted.
```

What would be an appropriate data structure for this, or would you suggest a custom algoritham?

Thanks,
-MT

Comment: Not sure why you need to do it like that, what is the main goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using recursion instead of a loop:

```
shift (list, index, index2) {
  if (index < list.size()){
    shift(index+1, index2+2)
    list[index2] = list[index]
  }
}
```

In that general direction :)